# How to solve the problem with Thread in QT (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-7, qthread

I am writing a program in C++ using QT. Task: The user can specify a directory that consists of other folders, and files are located inside these folders. It is necessary to archive the folders with the file and place the archives in another directory. I am working with an additional thread for processing (I created a Worker class, etc.). I did everything according to the example from the QT documentation. The problem is the following: Everything works on my computer and on computers with Windows 10. But on Windows 7 computers, after processing one large folder, the program crashes. Error: The program does not work, code 0xc0000005. What to do? Is this a problem in the code or do I need to install something additionally? Net Framework, Visual C++, etc. updated, but nothing helped. The program code is attached.

P.S. If you don't use an additional thread, then everything works correctly. But an additional thread is needed so that the processing progress can be displayed, that is, how many directories have been processed

```
#include "renamewidget.h"
#include "ui_renamewidget.h"
#include <private/qzipwriter_p.h>

QString RenameWidget::filePath;       //static field
QString RenameWidget::directoryPath;  //static field
QString RenameWidget::resultPath;     //static field

RenameWidget::RenameWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::RenameWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    filePath      = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/1.xlsx";
    directoryPath = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/2";
    resultPath    = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/3";

    connect(this, &RenameWidget::doWork, &worker, &Worker::doWork);
    connect(&worker, &Worker::workProgress, this, &RenameWidget::setText);
    worker.moveToThread(&thread);
    thread.start();
}


void RenameWidget::setText(QString message)
{
    ui->lableLoad->setText(message); // setProgress
}

void RenameWidget::on_pb_Rename_clicked()
{
        emit doWork();
}

void Worker::doWork()
{
        emit workProgress("");

        QDir dir;
        dir.setPath(RenameWidget::getDirectoryPath());
        QStringList listDir = dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot);

        for (int i = 0; i<listDir.size();i++)
        {
        QString article = QString::number(i);
            dir.setPath(RenameWidget::getDirectoryPath() + "/" + listDir.at(i));
            QStringList tempstr = dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot);
            
            QString temppath = RenameWidget::getDirectoryPath() + "/" + listDir.at(i) + "/" + tempstr .at(0);
            QString tempres  = RenameWidget::getResultPath() + "/" + "archives" + "/" + article;

            dir.mkpath(tempres);
            doArchive(temppath + "/", tempres + "/" + article + ".zip");

             emit workProgress("Обработано каталогов: " + QString::number(i+1) + "/" + QString::number(listDir.size()));
        }

        emit workProgress("Готово");
}

void Worker::doArchive(QString path, QString zippath)
{
    QZipWriter zip(zippath);

    zip.setCompressionPolicy(QZipWriter::AutoCompress);

    QDirIterator it(path, QDir::Files | QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        QString file_path = it.next();
        if (it.fileInfo().isFile())
        {
            QFile file(file_path);
            if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
                continue;
            zip.setCreationPermissions(QFile::permissions(file_path));
            QByteArray ba = file.readAll();
            zip.addFile(file_path.remove(path), ba);
        }
    }
    zip.close();
}
```

Comment: Looks OK on a first glance. You can try to use `std::async` instead of `QThread` and still `emit workProgress("xxx");` your progress.

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: @В.К. QT - 5.14.2